# Table class Problem in C++, with templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have a code in C++, where I have to create a private entity Array field of 500.There is also field which represents the amount of entities in table.

More Information about the class I want to create :

- defines all of its special member functions.
- defines a string constant method named ToString() that takes no parameters. It creates a string that is a list of its entites each on their own line.
- defines a void method named Insert() that takes a constant Entity reference parameter. It adds the parameter to the table if the table is not full and the key of the parameter is not in the table.
- defines a void method named Remove() that takes a constant Entity reference parameter. It removes the entity from the table whose key matches the key of the parameter. • defines an ulong constant method named Count() that takes no parameters. It returns the amount of entities in the table.
- defines an overloaded ostream operator. It displays the same format as ToString().
- defines a constant Entity reference constant overloaded subscript operator that takes an ulong parameter. If the parameter represents a valid index, it returns a element of the table whose index is equal to the parameter; otherwise, it throws an error.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Table {

public:
    string Entity[500];
    unsigned long size = 0;

    Table() {
        for(int i; i < 500; i++) {
            Entity[i] = "";
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    Table(const Table &obj) {
        for(int i; i < 500; i++) {
            Entity[i] = obj.Entity[i];
        }
    }

    template<typename Table>
    Table& operator=(const Table<T> &obj) {
        for(int i; i < 500; i++) {
            if(this != &obj) {
                Entity[i] = obj.Entity[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~Table() {}

    const string GetEntity() {
        for(int i; i < 500; i++){
            return Entity[i];
        }
    }

    void SetFN(string Entry, int idx) {
        Entity[idx] = Entry;
    }

    const string ToString() {
        string out = "{";
        for(unsigned long i; i < size; i++) {
            out = out + (Entity[i]);
            if(i < size - 1) {
                out = out + "\n";
            }
        }
        out = out + "}";
        return out;
    }

    friend ostream operator<<(ostream ost, Table& Tobj) {
        string out = "{";
        for(unsigned long i; i < size; i++) {
            out = out + to_string(Entity[i]);
            if(i < (size - 1)) {
                out = out + "\n";
            }
        }
        out = out + "}";
        ost << out;
        return ost;
    }

    void Insert(const Enity<T>&... data) {
        if(IsFull() && contains(data)) {
            Entity[size] == data;
        }
    }

    void Remove(const Entity<T> &data) {
        bool subtract = false;
        int subtractedIndex = - 1;
        for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(Entity[i] == obj) {
                subtract = true;
                subtractedIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if(subtract) {
            Entity[subtractedIndex] = Entity[size - 1];
            size--;
        }
    }

    const unsigned long Count() {
        return size;
    }

    // Overloaded Subcript Operator
    const Table& operator[](unsigned long pos) {
        for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(this != size){
                return Entity[pos];
            } else {
                return "Error";
            }
        }
    }
private:

    const bool Contains(const T &obj) {
        for(unsigned long i; i < size; i++) {
            if(Entity[i] == obj) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    const bool IsFull() {
        if(size == 500) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

But when I compile the code, it gives me the following errors:-

```
prblm.cpp:37:26: error: ‘Table’ is not a template
   37 | Table& operator = (const Table<T> &obj) {
      |                          ^~~~~
prblm.cpp:37:32: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
   37 | Table& operator = (const Table<T> &obj) {
      |                                ^
prblm.cpp:117:19: error: ‘Enity’ does not name a type
  117 | void Insert(const Enity<T>&... data){
      |                   ^~~~~
prblm.cpp:117:24: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
  117 | void Insert(const Enity<T>&... data){
      |                        ^
prblm.cpp:127:19: error: ‘Entity’ does not name a type
  127 | void Remove(const Entity<T> &data) {
      |                   ^~~~~~
prblm.cpp:127:25: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
  127 | void Remove(const Entity<T> &data) {
      |                         ^
prblm.cpp:183:27: error: ‘T’ does not name a type
  183 | bool const Contains(const T &obj) {
      |                           ^
prblm.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream, Table&)’:
prblm.cpp:97:19: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Table::size’
   97 | for (ulong i; i < size; i++){
      |                   ^~~~
prblm.cpp:15:7: note: declared here
   15 | ulong size = 0;
      |       ^~~~
prblm.cpp:99:23: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Table::Entity’
   99 | out = out + to_string(Entity[i]);
      |                       ^~~~~~
prblm.cpp:13:8: note: declared here
   13 | string Entity[500];
      |        ^~~~~~
prblm.cpp:101:10: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Table::size’
  101 | if (i < (size-1)) {
      |          ^~~~
prblm.cpp:15:7: note: declared here
   15 | ulong size = 0;
      |       ^~~~
prblm.cpp:113:8: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
  113 | return ost;
      |        ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from prblm.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:397:7: note: declared here
  397 |       basic_ostream(const basic_ostream&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
prblm.cpp: In member function ‘void Table::Insert(int)’:
prblm.cpp:119:26: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
  119 | if (IsFull() && contains(data) ) {
      |                          ^~~~
prblm.cpp:119:17: error: ‘contains’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘Contains’?
  119 | if (IsFull() && contains(data) ) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
      |                 Contains
prblm.cpp: In member function ‘void Table::Remove(int)’:
prblm.cpp:135:18: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
  135 | if (Entity[i] == obj) {
      |                  ^~~
prblm.cpp: In member function ‘const Table& Table::operator[](ulong)’:
prblm.cpp:167:13: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
  167 | if (this != size){
      |             ^~~~
prblm.cpp:169:18: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const Table&’ from expression of type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
  169 | return Entity[pos];
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~^
prblm.cpp:173:8: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const Table&’ from expression of type ‘const char [6]’
  173 | return "Error";
      |        ^~~~~~~
prblm.cpp: In member function ‘const bool Table::Contains(const int&)’:
prblm.cpp:187:14: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} and ‘const int’)
  187 | if(Entity[i] == obj) {
      |    ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~
      |            |    |
      |            |    const int
      |            std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
```

Comment: Why are you using templates at all? `Table` is not a template in the first place, so all those function templates are unnecessary.

Comment: There is a lot of little errors. The best you can do is try to understand every compiler message of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors. Some of them by quick view.

The first line:

> prblm.cpp:37:26: error: ‘Table’ **is not a template**

You declared Table as a normal class, then you use constructor / operaor template.
Either declare your class as template:

template < typename T >
class Table {};

Or remove "template" from constructor and operator.
Instead, declare separate function template Convert / Copy. Something like this:

```
template <class T>
void Copy( const T & src )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++ i)
    {
        Entity[i] = src.Entity[i].ToString();
    }
}
```

another error:

```
string const GetEntity() {

    for (int i; i < 500; i++){
        return Entity[i];
    }
}
```

It is absolutely unclear what did you want. Your variable "**i**" is not initialized and takes random value. If random value is less than 500 (even negative), it returns the E**ntity[i]**. In case of negative "**i**", application will crash.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it!